# Post request detected as bot with HTTPARTY but not with postman (same headers)

Tags: ruby, api, httprequest, httparty

I am trying to fetch a public API. When I do it from the postman everything works fine however when I do it from my app I get and error message: `<META NAME=\"robots\" CONTENT=\"noindex,nofollow\"`

I do not understand how this is possible?

Here is are the headers variables I adjust when I make my request with postman:

```
Cookie:"some cookie"
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type:application/json
Host:"some host"
```

Here is my httparty request:

```js
response = HTTParty.post(url, 
            :body => body_request (same as with postman),
            :headers => {
                'Content-Type' =>  'application/json',
                'cookie' => 'same cookie as above',
                'Host' => 'same host as above',
                'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache'         
            } 
)
```

Why would it work with postman but not with a httparty request?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would look into User-Agent, even if you don't explicitely set the header, your http client is still sending one.

Postman uses :
`"User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.26.8",`

while HTTParty is simply
`"User-Agent": "Ruby"`

Maybe your public API (could be more precise if we knew which) has a whitelist of 'non-bot' user agents and HTTParty is not among them

Try overriding it

```rb
resp = HTTParty.get 'https://httpbin.org/headers' , headers: {'User-Agent': 'xx'}
```